# Calculate the sum $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{(n+3)n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Solve $\int^1_0 x^2 e^x \,dx$ using the power series of $e^x$. This boils down to evaluating $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{(n+3)n!}$.

Usually, I solve the infinite sums by transforming them into integration by playing around with the power series of $e^x$. But I don't know how it can be done the other way around here.

Comment: hint: can you rewrite $(n+1)n!$ in a simpler form?

Comment: Sorry  I have corrected the problem.

Comment: You've changed $n+1$ to $n+3$ in your edit. Just highlighting this to other commenters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to check that
$$\frac1{(n+3)n!} = \frac1{(n + 1)!} - \frac2{(n + 2)!} + \frac2{(n + 3)!}.$$

Then you should know how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks that was a clever partial fraction.