# Sum of series in the form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n+k)\cdot n!}$ for some k>0

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I was recently given the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n+3)\cdot n!}$$ and was told that it evaluated to a very nice number of $e-2$.

However, I do not know how to arrive at that answer using any of the tricks I know. It is neither a geometric series, a p series, or a known Taylor series. Neither can I find any way to form an integral representation of $\frac{1}{(n+3)\cdot n!}$ so I can swap the integral and summation.

So how would I go about evaluating this?

More generally, how would I evaluate series with the form $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n+k)\cdot n!}$$ for a positive nonzero k?

Comment: multiply and divide numerator by $3$. then write numerator $3$ =$(n+3)-n$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662730/calculate-the-sum-sum-limits-infty-n-0-frac1n3n?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor series should be work well, since we need to find $S=\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{1}{n!(n+3)}$ so define $\displaystyle f(x):=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{x^{n+3}}{n!(n+3)}$, then $f'(x)=x^{2}e^{x}$ so $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}e^{t}\, {\rm d}t$ and therefore $S=f(1)$. The same method work for the general case $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{1}{n!(n+k)}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-1}e^{x}\, {\rm d}x=(-1)^{-k}\Gamma(k,0,-1)$ and $k>0$ according Mathematica.

Comment: Corrected the typo. $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n+k)\cdot n!}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{ n!}\int_0^1t^{k+n-1}dt=\int_0^1e^tt^{k-1}dt$$
Integrating by part
$$=e-(k-1)e+(k-1)(k-2)e+\,-...+(-1)^{k+1}(k-1)(k-2)\cdot\,...\cdot2\cdot e+(-1)^k(k-1)!(e-1)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav's result simplifies in terms of [subfactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) to $(-1)^k((k-1)!-!(k-1)e)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the nice comment of @Svyatoslav deserves an answer by its own.

We recall the identity
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1x^n\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align*}
and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)n!}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^{n+k-1}\,dx\frac{1}{n!}\\
&=\int_{0}^1x^{k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^1x^{k-1}e^x\,dx\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^k(k-1)!\left(1-e\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\right)}
\end{align*}
The last line can be derived using integration by parts together with a proof based upon induction on $k$.